# Чтение сообщения на телефоне

Tags: php

Как можно организовать программно чтение входящих смс-сообщений на мой номер?

Comment: платформа-то какая?

Comment: Хочу это дело сделать на php. Операторы предоставляют хоть какое-нибудь API или нужно с бубоном и андроидом плясать?

Comment: Операторы предоставляют хоть какое-нибудь API или нужно с бубоном и андроидом плясать?

Comment: ... или с Arduino

Comment: @Fike, гениальная визуализация.

Comment: ну я как-то это делал с древними сименсами, думаю со свистком-модемом тоже можно такое делать, есть доки  на at команды таких модемов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение все-таки нашел.

Оказалось, что самым лучшим способом получить текст СМС - это настроить услугу у оператора, где сообщения отправляются на электронную почту. Далее PHP-скриптом можно через API почты его получить.

Answer (score 2):

Я, пожалуй, визуализирую

```
PHP                                        Принятие СМС 
...                                        ............
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
(бездонная яма с шипами, простирающаяся между двумя
 сферами деятельности, которая неистово дожидается
                     авантюристов)
```

Ни один оператор не даст АПИ для чтения смс, это вам не oauth с контактиком, в контактик не шлют одноразовые банковские пароли. Да и вообще они их вряд ли хранят.

Да, придется каким-то образом связывать симку и компьютер.